# One pattern used as fill in different paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have the following pattern inside a svg

```
<pattern id="1" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="10" fill="blue"/>
</pattern>
```

Now what Im trying to accomplish is use this pattern as a fill inside different paths, each of them setting setting some property and then applying it.

When I currently run it every path where the pattern got applied changes to the newly set property.

Is there a way so that this property change only applies to the current path leaving the old paths in tacked. Kind of like cloning?

ps. I have tried creating the pattern in javascript and then appending it to the defs element but that doesnt seem to be working.

Currently trying to do it like this

```
var data = ['a','b','c'];

    function set() {
        if(data.length > 0) {
            var counter = 0;
            var el = $('#' + data.splice(0, 1));
            var x = el[0].getBBox().width / 2;
            var y = el[0].getBBox().height / 2;

            var pattern = $('#1');
            pattern.attr('cx', x);
            pattern.attr('cy', y);

            setTimeout(set, 1000);
        }
    }

    function fillPath(el, pattern, counter) {
        if(counter < 11) {
            counter++;
            pattern.attr('r', pattern.attr('r') + 10);
            el.attr('fill', 'url(#1)');
            setTimeout(fillPath(el, pattern, counter), 50);
        } else {
            el.attr('fill', 'blue');
        }
    }
```

I understand why it changes as there is just one instance of it. Is there a way to make a copy of it use it and the discard it once done?

EDIT

Tried a different approach

```
    function set() {
        var pattern = document.createElementNS('http;//www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'pattern');
        pattern.setAttribute("x","0");
        pattern.setAttribute("y","0");
        pattern.setAttribute("width","1");
        pattern.setAttribute("height","0");

        var circle = document.createElementNS('http;//www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
        circle.setAttribute("cx","90");
        circle.setAttribute("cy","90");
        circle.setAttribute("r","10");
        circle.setAttribute("fill","blue");

        pattern.appendChild(circle);
        if(data.length > 0) {
            var counter = 0;
            console.log("is");
            var el = $('#' + data.splice(0, 1));

            var x = el[0].getBBox().width / 2;
            var y = el[0].getBBox().height / 2;

            fillPath(el, pattern, counter);

            setTimeout(set, 1000);
        }
    }

    function fillPath(el, pattern, counter) {
        if(counter < 11) {
            counter++;
            pattern.firstChild.attr('r', pattern.firstChild.attr('r') + 10);
            console.log(pattern);
            el.attr('fill', pattern);
            setTimeout(fillPath(el, pattern, counter), 50);
        }
    }
```

Now for some reason the pattern that i log all has the same values as the last one that was created.
Somewhere its still binding to the same var.

Comment: How are you applying the pattern's currently?

Comment: You're going to need multiple patterns.

Comment: The thing with that is the dataset is really big upto 700 a minute, now if I have 10 patterns the fillPattern function will be called at a high rate thus the cx and cy will constantly change. As there are 220 paths having 10 pattern for each one seems highly wrong.

Comment: Sounds like SVG is the wrong technology for you and you should be on canvas instead then.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I got it working is to create the pattern in javascript and append it to the defs tag giving it an id.

So then it went was to first check if the id is already there and if its not then create the pattern append it to defs and use it.

Worked very nicely.